# What is the difference between a node and a machine on OpenShift?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

OpenShift 4.2 documentation defines:

> **Machines**
>
> A fundamental unit that describes the host for a Node. A machine has a providerSpec, which describes the types of compute nodes that
>   are offered for different cloud platforms. For example, a machine type
>   for a worker node on Amazon Web Services (AWS) might define a specific
>   machine type and required metadata.

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.1/machine_management/creating-machineset.html

While Kubernetes doc defines:

> **Nodes**
>
> A node is a worker machine in Kubernetes, previously known as a
>   minion. A node may be a VM or physical machine, depending on the
>   cluster. Each node contains the services necessary to run pods and is
>   managed by the master components. The services on a node include the
>   container runtime, kubelet and kube-proxy. See The Kubernetes Node
>   section in the architecture design doc for more details.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/

I don't know whether Kubernetes has the concept of *machines*, and I can't find on OpenShift's documentation its own definition of *node* (perhaps it uses Kubernetes'?)

And I can't get what's the difference between them.  My current understanding is that a machine represents a raw physical or virtual machine; just the computational resources like cpu, memory and storage.  Nodes, then, would represent a machine that is configured for using with OpenShift, that is, a machine that *contains the services necessary to run pods and is managed by the master components*.

Another theory would be that machines are just an abstraction to the existing infrastructure, so that persistent labels can be assigned to them for organizing the infrastructure, and as a way to provide information on the underlying infrastructure properties for the nodes.

So...  What is really the difference between nodes and machines?  Is a node in OpenShift exactly the same thing as in Kubernetes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct:

> My current understanding is that a machine represents a raw physical or virtual machine; just the computational resources like cpu, memory and storage. Nodes, then, would represent a machine that is configured for using with OpenShift, that is, a machine that contains the services necessary to run pods and is managed by the master components.

The differences arise on the level of abstraction.

- A Node in OpenShift is exactly the same thing as a Kubernetes node. It refers to the abstraction of a worker/master "Node" in a "Cluster". The Node abstraction only exists within the boundaries of a running cluster.
- A Machine is an abstraction introduced by the [Cluster API](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cluster-api) which is an ongoing effort to allow deploying K8S clusters using a declarative approach. OpenShift is currently adopting the Cluster API hence they expect you to define the host infrastructure required to run your Nodes using the Machine spec.

Comment: just a suggestion to add a link to the Concepts page of the book, and perhaps a bit of its description of the Machine concept:

https://cluster-api.sigs.k8s.io/user/concepts.html

Answer (score 1):

Basically, a Node is just a simple worker OpenShift (or Kubernetes) instance where OpenShift can schedule Pods.

`Machine` is a new API introduce by OpenShift 4 that manage dynamic instance provisioning on top of public (AWS, Azure...) or private (OpenStack, VMWare...) cloud provider.